# Reset Scan Accumulator RxJS after certain time

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a fromEvent attached to input keydown event. This way I can listen to KeyEvents.

Inside the pipe, I use the scan operator, so I can accumulate the latest 3 keys introduced by the user.

I check in the scan, the accumulator length, so if it's already three, I clean it up (manual reset).

I need a way that when the user types in, within the next 3000ms, he can keep typing until reaching the limit (3 keys) but if the user is slower than the time limit (3s), next time he types in, I will reset the accumulator manually.

```
  fromEvent(myInput.nativeElement, 'keydown').pipe(
    tap(e => e.preventDefault()),
    scan((acc: KeyboardEvent[], val: KeyboardEvent) => {
      // Add condition here to manually reset the accumulator...
      if (acc.length === 3) {
        acc = [];
      }
      return [...acc, val];
    }, []),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subscribe((events: KeyboardEvent[]) => console.log(events));
```

I have tried to merge this with a timer in some way, but I can't figure out how. Not sure how to get there.

Comment: I'm confused here. you want to reset the accumulator at 3 key strokes or 3 seconds, whichever comes first?

Comment: Exactly @bryan60 - I am going to add your comment as it resumes quite clear my goal here. Thanks.

Comment: does every keystroke reset the 3 second timer?

Comment: Yep. Just one little detail, it supports 3 keystrokes, when the accumulator is 3 and enter the scan, it is the 4th so we reset and add that one as the first value of the new result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `timeInterval` operator here, which gives you the time passed between emissions along with the value. set up along the lines of:

```
  fromEvent(myInput.nativeElement, 'keydown').pipe(
    tap(e => e.preventDefault()),
    timeInterval(), // just add this operator, will convert to shape {value: T, interval: number}
    scan((acc: KeyboardEvent[], val) => {
      // Add condition here to manually reset the accumulator...
      // also check the interval
      if (acc.length === 3 || val.interval > 3000) {
        acc = [];
      }
      return [...acc, val.value];
    }, []),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
   ).subscribe((events: KeyboardEvent[]) => console.log(events));
```

here is a working blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dxfb37?file=index.ts

not an operator I've ever had a use case for before, but seems to solve your issue here pretty effectively.

Comment: Probably,  this if statement  should return empty array instead of assignment

if (acc.length === 3 || val.interval > 3000) {
        return [];
}

Comment: @a_zatula I do not believe that's what OP wants. I think it should reset the array and emit the new value if > 3 seconds have passed

Comment: It works like a charm, this is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks. By the way, I added the type:   (val: TimeInterval<KeyboardEvent>) => {...